# Python unittest AssertionError not being raised

Tags: python, unit-testing, assert, python-unittest

I am trying to write unit tests for my Python package, and I am finding that, when I run the tests, AssertionErrors are not being raised, when they should be. Here is an [MWE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimal_working_example):

In *exampleModule.py* I have:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python
import unittest

class UnitTest(unittest.TestCase):

    def runTest(self):
        print("Starting test...")
        a = 4
        b = 5
        self.assertEqual(a,b)
        print("TEST COMPLETE")
        return
```

And in *testError.py* I have:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python
import unittest

class AllTests(unittest.TestCase):

    def testExample(self):
        from exampleModule import UnitTest
        UT = UnitTest()
        UT.run()
        return

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

When I run testError.py I expect to see the AssertionError reported from the UnitTest in exampleModule.py, however, I simply see the following:

```
> ./testError.py
Starting test...
.
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.001s

OK
```

Why is the AssertionError not being raised? If I place the UnitTest() class in testError.py (i.e., have everything in the same file) then the AssertionError is raised. So why, when UnitTest is stored in a different file, does the error not get raised?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.assertRaises

Comment: Thanks @Gang -- so where do I put the call to assertRaises()? In my AllTests class? Is the context manager returned by the TestCase.run() call? If I am understanding correct, any error raised inside the UnitTest.runTest() function is ignored and simply stored in the context manager? Querying the context manager inside my UnitTest.runTest() function simply creates another AssertionError, that is also "ignored".

Comment: it is meaningless to to test a unittest using another unittest.

Comment: @Gang -- so how would I restructure my example such that I can have an individual test stored in a module, and have a script that calls all those tests and runs them using the main() function?

Comment: do you means `nosetests` or `nose2` or `pytest`, they will discover and make tests without using the `__main__`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`TestCase.run()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.run)
creates or updates a
[`TestResult`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestResult)
object, on the assumption you intend to do something interesting with those results.

But you immediately throw them away:

```
    UT.run()
```

Any failures or errors—including exceptions raised—would have been in that results object.

For example:

```
def testExample(self):
    from exampleModule import UnitTest
    UT = UnitTest()
    result = UT.run()
    print('Errors:  {!r}'.format(result.errors))
    print('Failures:  {!r}'.format(result.failures))
    return
```

This prints:

> **Failures**:  [(<exampleModule.UnitTest testMethod=runTest>, 'Traceback (most recent call last):\n  File "/home/kjc/tmp/exampleModule.py", line 11, in runTest\n    self.assertEqual(a, b)\n**AssertionError: 4 != 5**\n')]

It catches all kinds of exceptions, like this example where I added `sys.exit()` before the assertion:

> **Errors**:  [(<exampleModule.UnitTest testMethod=runTest>, 'Traceback (most recent call last):\n  File "/home/kjc/tmp/exampleModule.py", line 11, in runTest\n    import sys; sys.exit()\n**SystemExit**\n')]

For the record, the one passing test your example produced is `testExample` itself.
You can verify this by calling `self.fail()` early in `testExample`.
(As one commentator said, calling unit tests *from* a unit test is a very strange thing to do.)

### One Solution

You seem to want to run tests normally, but from multiple files.
If so, you can make a bunch of typical
[`unittest.main()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#unittest.main)-style
test modules, and then load them manually.

Your test-everything script would look something like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import unittest


# Edit this to include new modules or TestCases to run.
_NAMES = ['testmoda', 'testmodb']  # testothermodule.SomeTestCase, etc...


def _main():
    suite = unittest.defaultTestLoader.loadTestsFromNames(_NAMES)
    unittest.TextTestRunner().run(suite)
    return  # WARNING: This always returns a successful exit value.


if __name__ == '__main__':
    _main()
```

Your test modules would be the usual one-or-more `TestCase`s, with conditional calls to `unittest.main()`, so each could be run independently:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import unittest


class TestModA(unittest.TestCase):

    def testThatPasses(self):
        self.assertEqual(0, -0)
        return

    def testThatFails(self):
        self.assertEqual(0, float('inf'))
        return

    def testThatBlowsUp(self):
        raise RuntimeError('OMG!')
        return


if '__main__' == __name__:
    unittest.main()
```

If that's not fiddly enough for you, you can also read up on the
[`discover()` method](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestLoader.discover)
or the module-level
[`load_tests` protocol](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#load-tests-protocol).

Comment: Great! Thanks for the explanation -- think I understand better now. Thanks also for your suggested solution!

Answer (score 0):

The convention to structure unittests is like this:

Hold all tests in `tests` directory.

test module will be named as `test_modulea.py` with `class TestClassA`

`nosetests -vw tests` to run all tests.